# Как убрать лишнее пустое пространство сверху и снизу в seaborn.scatterplot?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Собственно, по заголовку наверное все понятно, так что просто приведу скрин. То же самое и снизу, как от этого избавиться чтобы смысловая часть графика занимала все пространство?
[image]

Comment: Выставьте `plt.xlim` и `plt.ylim` на нужные диапазоны значений. Надо было мне в том ответе дописать, но на моих данных и так было нормально. По идее `seaborn` вроде бы и так не должен лишнего рисовать. Может вам просто `figsize` уменьшить, у вас он там какой-то бешеный, на все значения предназначенный был, а стало ведь гораздо меньше значений в итоге. Там у вас по `y` какой-то нереальный был размер.

Comment: Ничерта не понятно по заголовку. Пустое пространство что? Есть? или нужно добавить?

Comment: @strawdog Да я так понимаю, это в продолжение вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1342713/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-seaborn-scatterplot-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8 там размер отрисовываемых данных уменьшился, а `figsize` прежний остался, вот поля лишние и висят теперь.

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо, я думал еще написать в том же вопросе, но подумал это все таки уже совсем другой вопрос, лучше создать новый. С размерами я уж играл, но если поставить меньше то все данные ужмутся, но пустота все равно останется. ylim помогло, спасибо!

Comment: @PetrEinerin Раз помогло, добавлю ответом )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выставьте `plt.xlim` и `plt.ylim` на нужные диапазоны значений. Возможно, нужно будет ещё поиграться `figsize`.